# Does it count as me landing the killing blow if a monster dies to a Wound that I inflicted?

Tags: gloomhaven

Some of the personal quests involve killing a certain number of monsters. The official FAQ has clarified that the character must be the one to land the killing blow in order for it to count towards the quest. What happens if I perform an attack that inflicts Wound on the monster, and they later die as a result of that Wound. Do I still get credit for killing that monster? We ruled that it did just because it seemed reasonable to give the character credit in that way, but I'm curious if there is an official ruling on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]My question: *When a monster dies due to the wound I've inflicted, does it count as my kill?*

The answer Isaac Childres emailed me:

> *if a monster dies from wound, no one would get credit.*

Isaac has now repeated this answer [on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/25213787#25213787).

Comment: Could you please explain why this is the case?

Comment: Please update this answer to give some context about where/what you asked. _e.g._ "I asked the designer on BGG [link to the post]; he said _." It may be the right answer but we have no way of seeing that from what you've provided.

Comment: @Chenmunka: The reason is probably that there's enough stuff to track in the game without having to track who inflicted every wound in the game, and tracking would also require extra components. The rules as written has to be a compromise between detail and streamline. There's no reason you can't houserule additional detail though, if that's what your group prefers.