# Gloomhaven: Does it count as me landing the killing blow if a monster dies to my retaliate?

Tags: gloomhaven

Related to [Does it count as me landing the killing blow if a monster dies to a Wound that I inflicted?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/34355/25666), will a character get credit (for Personal Quests/Battle Goals) for killing a monster if the monster dies due to retaliate damage inflicted by that character?

Comment: The answer in the linked question points to [this thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/25213787#25213787), where the consensus seems to be that *yes, you get credit for the kill.* Obviously that's not enough to base a stack exchange answer on, but that would be good enough for me and my group to consider it answered.

Comment: And, honestly,"retaliate" semantically implies action on the part of the character, so thematically I would say 100% yes.

But then again, I don't play with the whole "invisible sitting a doorway" thing being OK because thematically that just seems dumb, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 7):

I would say **yes** based on the fact I have seen retaliate being a persistent bonus (rulebook p25).  In this case at least, using the retaliate actively takes something away from your character.

Contrarily, in the case of the wound, the status affect has already been applied and nothing is taken away from your character when it harms.

Tangentially, I also think the wound ruling is to prevent the complexity of trying to keep track of who did what wound (as far as I've seen not accounted for in the game; you'd need to either markup tokens, keep paper track, etc.).  Retaliate it's obvious since it's reactive.

Comment: Could you clarify who gets the credit, the char whose ability grants the retaliate, or the char granted the ability to retaliate?

Comment: For wounding, it also avoids the issue of who gets credit if multiple chars wounded a monster

Comment: Are wounds cumulative? For some reason, I thought it was a binary condition.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0, Binary.